# Audiokit header file not found

Tags: header, audiokit, file-not-found

I started a new project and installed audiokit cocoa pods. I created a new h file. when I try to #import “AKAudioUnit.h” (or any other Audiokit h file) I get a “file not found” error.

Comment: Thanks for trying out AudioKit, but unfortunately you haven't really provided a lot of information for anyone to help you.

Comment: @AureliusProchazka I installed cocoa pods into my new project, created a new h file, then tried to import a header file from the audiokit cocoa pods that I just installed. Am I missing something? Is there more to it that I didn’t do?

Comment: can someone please share a solution I have been stuck on this for a while. I’ve tried reinstalling the pod-file, checking if frameworks are missing, etc. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: I have also tried importing header files one by one, but after 15+ imports, I get an error stating that there are duplicate declarations!

Comment: I'm sorry but there's still a lot of information to go on.  Why don't you try AudioKit from source instead of using Cocoapods if it is causing you a roadblock?

Comment: Sorry, I mean, NOT a lot of information to go on.